# Insert JSON array in mysql db from a php file

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hello i have a `JSon` array like this

```
   Array
  (
    [NTAy] => ALFA ROMEO
    [NTA0] => AUDI
    [NTEx] => BMW
    [NjAy] => CHEVROLET
    [NTEz] => CHRYSLER
    [NTE0] => CITROËN
    [NjAz] => DACIA
    [NjQ5] => DAEWOO
    [NTE3] => DAIHATSU
  )
```

and I have to insert it in a database row by row, I used

```
foreach ($mata as $marca_id => $marca_name){
    $line = $line. "','" . $marca_id . "','". $marca_name . "','". $marca_name;
}
$line = substr($line, 0, strlen($line)-1);
$values[$i] = $line;
++$i;

$values =implode ( $values);
echo $values;
echo "<br />";
```

but at the mysql insert

```
$data = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO jos_virtuemart_categories_ro_ro (virtuemart_category_id, category_name, slug) 
VALUES " .$values)
```

I get an error and can't get it to work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What's `$i` doing outside the `foreach` loop? What do you want the query to be?

Comment: @AmalMurali I think OP does not have a proper understanding of how INSERT statements work, nor loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($mata as $marca_id => $marca_name) {
    $id = intval($marca_id);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($marca_name);
    $values = "$id, '$name', '$name'";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO jos_virtuemart_categories_ro_ro (virtuemart_category_id, category_name, slug) VALUES ($values)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use prepared statements? Especially if you're taking user generated data and entering it into your database.

That and it looks like you're final SQL query will look like this

```
INSERT INTO jos_virtuemart_categories_ro_ro (virtuemart_category_id, category_name, slug) 
VALUES 'NTAy','ALFA ROMEO','ALFA ROMEO','NTA0','AUDI','AUDI' etc
```

You would have to break this up into multiple queries