# How do I insert data from a json array into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying for some time now to insert data from a JSON array into mysql database using php but what ever I try it is not working.

my array looks like so...

```
Array  
(  
    [] => -4.0533  
    [bert] => 2
    [earnie] => 0.25  
    [bigbird] => 0.25  
    [grouch] => 1.25  
)
```

I am trying to insert this data into mysql database that has a table named "useramounts"
the table contains 2 columns. (username,amount) so that each row contains a username and the associated amount

this is probably very simple for you guys but I have never attempted this before. I have tried to google a solution but to no avail. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Perhaps reading up on PHP/MySQL and following a tutorial is a better place to start.  If you have a specific question during the process, feel free to ask it here.

Comment: thanks joel for your polite response but i give up now so dont worry about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert JSON array in mysql db from a php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429028/insert-json-array-in-mysql-db-from-a-php-file)

Comment: @noloader: The linked question does have an answer that is encouraging bad practice (it's creating an insert per loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried?

Try this approach:

- Convert JSON to PHP array ([`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode))
- Loop through the array, get the key and value for each entry ([`foreach(){}`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/array_keys))
- Create a single string with an insert and add `VALUES()` for each row
- Execute the query after the loop

  ```
   $keys = array_keys($array);              // get the value of keys
   $rows = array();                         // create a temporary storage for rows
   foreach($keys as $key) {                 // loop through
       $value = $array[$key];               // get corresponding value
       $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";
                                            // add a row to the temporary storage 
   }
   $values = implode(",", $rows);           // 'glue' your rows into a query
   $query = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES " . $values;
                                            // write the rest of your query
   ...                                      // execute query
  ```

As soon as you find a concrete question, feel free to open another post.