# How to place the json objects into array usin php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

this is my php code, to obtain json format data

```
if($status==1)
    {
        $post_id=$json_object['post_id'];

        $get_postid=mysqli_query($con,"select * from User_Post where post_id='$post_id'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_postid)==0)
        {

            //For failure status if session id is wrong.
             http_response_code(500);
             echo json_encode(array("error_code"=>"500","error_message"=>"Sorry, post id does not exists."));
        }
        else
        {
        foreach($field_check as $values)
        {
            if($values=='id')
            {
                $row_array = array();
                while ($row = $get_postid->fetch_array())
                {
                    $row_array['id']=$row['post_id'];
                    $row_array['image_urls']=explode(',',$row['post_image_url']);
                    $storetag= explode(',',$row['Post_tagged_id']);   
                    $has_liked="false";
                    $has_commented="false";

                }

            }
            elseif($values=='tagged_users')
            {

                while ($row = $get_postid->fetch_array())
                {
                    $storetag= explode(',',$row['Post_tagged_id']);
                    $has_liked="false";
                    $has_commented="false";
                }
                for($i=0;$i<count($storetag);$i++)
                {

                    $user=mysqli_query($con,"select user_id, profile_image_url from Wheel_User where user_id='$storetag[$i]'");

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($user)==0)
                    {
                        //For failure status if session id is wrong.
                        http_response_code(500);
                        echo json_encode(array("error_code"=>"500","error_message"=>"Sorry, post id does not exists.".die()));
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        while ($row = $user->fetch_array())
                        {

                            $tagged_users[$i]['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
                            $array['user_id']=$tagged_users[$i]['user_id'];
                            $pro_image_url[$i]=$row['profile_image_url'];
                            $short_image_url[$i]=str_replace('_b','_t',$pro_image_url[$i]);
                            $short_image_url[$i]=str_replace('/images/','/thumbnails/',$short_image_url[$i]);
                            $array['short_image_url']=$short_image_url[$i];

                        }

                    }

                    array_push($row_array,$array);

                }

            }

        }

            array_push($json_response,$row_array);
            echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($json_response)); 
    }
}
```

It is returning the following objects

```
[
{
"id": "1111",
"image_urls": [
  "https://docs.google.com/document/d/14kVqw9d2kzYIEClN-SVp2Co2mlglM9F-8HIy0ggTZ3g/edit",
  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762150/how-do-i-insert-data-from-a-json-array-into-mysql-database",
  "https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#my-drive",
  "https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#shared-with-me"
 ],

"0": {
  "user_id": "111",
  "short_image_url": "chrome://restclient/content/thumbnails/restclient_t.jpg"
},
"1": {
  "user_id": "321",
  "short_image_url": "chrome://restclient/thumbnails/restclient_t.jpg"
},
"2": {
  "user_id": "1234",
  "short_image_url": "http://54.169.40.195/wheel/wheel/service/testing/chetan/audio/c71dfe45421b2864476a0bde257f0a57e72084783ce859e26595599670904907.mp3"
 }
 }
]
```

but i want to assign name to that array like this

```
[
  {
  "id": "1111",
  "image_urls": [
  "https://docs.google.com/document/d/14kVqw9d2kzYIEClN-SVp2Co2mlglM9F-8HIy0ggTZ3g/edit",
  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762150/how-do-i-insert-data-from-a-json-array-into-mysql-database",
  "https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#my-drive",
  "https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#shared-with-me"
  ],

 "tagged_users":[
"0": {
  "user_id": "111",
  "short_image_url": "chrome://restclient/content/thumbnails/restclient_t.jpg"
},
"1": {
  "user_id": "321",
  "short_image_url": "chrome://restclient/thumbnails/restclient_t.jpg"
},
"2": {
  "user_id": "1234",
  "short_image_url": "http://54.169.40.195/wheel/wheel/service/testing/chetan/audio/c71dfe45421b2864476a0bde257f0a57e72084783ce859e26595599670904907.mp3"
}
]
```

}
i don't know where i have to add this array name. Please help me solve this.
I can't assign the array name like this because $row_array also contains other data

```
echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode(array("tagged_user"=>$json_response));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
array_push($row_array['tagged_users'],$array);
```

Or define it like -

```
$row_array['tagged_users'] = array();
```

Then all the values will be as you want.

Comment: i tried it but it gives an error "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null"

Comment: And the row_array contains already two more values, so if i assign the name to row array then it will assign the name to whole json array. i hope you understood what i am telling.

Comment: Where do you defining `$row_array`?

Comment: at the beginning of code, when i started to put values in that array. so it has already two more values

Comment: Now i uploaded my whole code, i hope now you will get the clear picture,

Answer (score 0):

On second to last line this should be what you wanted:

```
array_push($json_response,array("tagged_users" => $row_array));
```

Edited to remove second part.

Comment: Now i uploaded my whole code, i hope now you will get the clear picture,

Comment: it works perfectly, but tagged_user should be an array i.e "tagged_user":[............      .....]

Comment: Ok then, if it's not doing that then it must be in the array push you do before that this also should be in your loop array_push($row_array,array( $i => $array)); add that as well